# fatal error: utils/UniquePtr.h: No such file or directory error

Tags: android, build

I'm trying to build android-4.3_r1.1 (JWR66Y) android for Nexus 7 wifi (full_grouper-userdebug) on 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04.4 desktop. I'm getting an error message during [make -j4](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html#build-the-code) step, which looks like

```
vendor/nvidia/grouper/keymaster/keymaster_grouper.cpp:39:29: fatal error: utils/UniquePtr.h: No such file or directory
```

I did download the proprietary binaries, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers). Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that **UniquePtr.h** has been moved to libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/ folder.  For the compiler to find it, you will need to edit two files:

First edit the makefile `vendor/nvidia/grouper/keymaster/Android.mk` and insert `libnativehelper/include` line like so:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    libcore/include \
    libnativehelper/include \
    external/openssl/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../security/tf_sdk/include
```

Then edit `vendor/nvidia/grouper/keymaster/keymaster_grouper.cpp`, go to line 39 and change the include as follows:

```
//#include <utils/UniquePtr.h>
#include <nativehelper/UniquePtr.h>
```

Then run your `make -j4` or whatever number you use and it should compile just fine.  It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix (not sure if it "safe", but the device boots and runs just fine now):

I did a search for UniquePtr.h and found it in another folder and copied it over. So go to what AOSP calls WORKING_DIRECTORY and do

```
cp libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/UniquePtr.h out/target/product/grouper/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/keystore.grouper_intermediates/utils/
```

and then

```
make -j4
```

again.

Answer (score 0):

As your out/ directory may be cleaned, it would be safer to add an include directory to the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variable of vendor/nvidia/grouper/keymaster/Android.mk

An other thing is that I don't have UniquePtr.h in libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/ on my 4.3_r2.1 AOSP source code but rather in libcore/include

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem building grouper for 4.4 (KRT16S).  There is a lib/core/utils/UniquePtr.h that works.  The one in libnativehelper now picks up a c++ algorithm file.

Use the one in lib/core, check that include path is correct in keymaster_grouper.cpp

Hard to believe this ever compiled.